# Format Java Import Statements with IntelliJ's Command Line Formatter

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ's code formatter from the command line (as described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter)) but it does not seem to format import statements.

Is this a known limitation, and is there anyway to work around it? Unfortunately, I specifically need to reorder import statements in a large amount of files.

Answer (score 0):

This script only reformats code, it doesn't perform imports optimization.